# Query about the functionality of Elastic Search on updation of database

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created elastic search index for search on my MySql database using python flask API, i want to know if the database is updated with new tables and records, Will the index be updated by itself, or I have to create the index again or do versioning of the index manually?

Comment: Please tag it properly. Is it of mysql or elasticsearch /

Comment: It is elastic search actually. i am creating elastic search index by querying mysql database. But when the index is generated then how to add new data into it, if my db is constantly updating , how we can implement that into our application.